# Building .net-core apps with 3rd party libraries

Tags: build, .net-core, nuget

I have a dot net core console app that I want to package up as a .exe and distribute to colleagues.

As all the users of the product are on Windows 10 I build the project using

```
dotnet build -r win10-x64
```

This is great in that it gives a small deployment package. Now that I have introduced 3rd party libraries (via nuget) I have a problem in that they are not included in the build output.

Is there a way to build a dot net core project as a .exe, including 3rd party libraries but not all the dot net libraries?

### Solution Found

Following @turobo's lead from below, I ended up with the following:

```
dotnet publish  -r win10-x64  -c Release --self-contained false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You need to use "dotnet publish" command to create a dotnet package. In dotnet core, the build command is not supposed to create a package that is distributable.

Excerpt from [dotnet build reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build):

> If the project has third-party dependencies, such as libraries from
>   NuGet, they're resolved from the NuGet cache and aren't available with
>   the project's built output. With that in mind, the product of dotnet
>   build isn't ready to be transferred to another machine to run. This is
>   in contrast to the behavior of the .NET Framework in which building an
>   executable project (an application) produces output that's runnable on
>   any machine where the .NET Framework is installed. To have a similar
>   experience with .NET Core, you need to use the [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) command.
>   For more information, see [.NET Core Application Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index).

What you are looking for is Framework-dependent executables (FDE). Excerpt from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index):

> Framework-dependent executables. Produces an executable that runs on a
>   target platform. Similar to FDDs, framework-dependent executables
>   (FDE) are platform-specific and aren't self-contained. These
>   deployments still rely on the presence of a shared system-wide version
>   of .NET Core to run. Unlike an SCD, your app only contains your code
>   and any third-party dependencies that are outside of the .NET Core
>   libraries. FDEs produce an executable that runs on the target
>   platform.

This should work:

```
dotnet publish -r win10-x64
```

Comment: Yes to the publish command. I ended up using the command as per my edited question above. Thanks for the pointers though.